# How to show a link in an HTML page with a huge size?

Tags: html, css, mobile-browser

To my web-portal, I have three simple HTML pages to download apps from iOS-, Android- and Microsoft-stores (if a mobile user load the portal from a mobile-browser).

On the pages I show some description text and - at the bottom of the page - I have a button (iOS-page) and links (as button don't work) on the Android and Windows Phone-pages.

If the user then click/tap on the button / link, the user is redirected to the download-page of the shop.

I have noted, that I have to set different font-sizes for all platforms to reach a usable result in general.
The font-sizes **to the text** are showed correct on all platforms.

The problem is, that the applied **fontsize *to the link* don't work** on the Windows Phone- and Android mobile browser. It seems as it is simply ignored, where the other elements (Text) are showed correct. The Link is showed way smaller as the text although it should be showed with a **greater** font.
Where in standard-browsers (Internet Explorer, Firefox, and Google Chrome) all works like it should (including Link-font-size).
I also have tried to set the size over attributes "XX-Large" -> same effect...

**Class - example to Windows Phone-Page:**

```
.WP_Link
 {
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size: 36px;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: #03C;
}
```

**Link - example to Windows Phone-Page:**

```
<a href="http://---the link" title="WP App laden" target="_blank" class="WP_Link">App jetzt aus Shop laden...</a>
```

**So my questions:**

- **Is there a way to show a link in the mobile browsers in a defined (huge) font-size?**
- **Is there a better way to show an button / link (with a link behind), that works on all mobile-browsers?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should use the font size in em, this will make a cross platform design easier. Check this: [CSS font size](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/)

Then, you can check the support that each browser gives to each tag here: [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-attribute)

So, if you want a cross-browser solution is better using a link and style it as a button. And if you want a huge font-size, just set the font size in a high em number.

Answer (score 2):

**First question.**

Ever heard of CSS `media queries`?

```
/* Big screen */
@media screen and (min-width: 621px) {
    /* Declare here your font-size for large screen (desktop browsers) */
}
/* Small screen */
@media screen and (max-width: 620px) {
    /*declare here your font-size for small screen (mobile screens)*/
}
```

You can also put this: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>` in your ''. It makes every pixel the same size.

[More information about that meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

**Second question.**

Style your link like a button. For example this:

```
 .link {
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid black;
    background:#222;
    color:#ccc;
 }
 .link:hover {
    background:green;
 }
```

So now it looks like a button, but it is actually a link and in combination with the `media queries` you can get it nice looking/fitting for all screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that was fast (answers).
Thanks to Vinc and Ivan.
**If I could, I would accept both postings as answers.**
I now have implemented a **"button-like" link to all platform-htmls** (see below) and changed the size to **em**.
I further had some problems with the code. I have created the pages with Dreamweaver and now have noted, that terrible code was generated (multiple tags, wrong tags, etc.). Therefore, I have edited (cleaned) the code now manually. 
Further, it seems, as (only) the WP- mobile browser has - why ever - a problem with 1em in a table (where e.g. 2 em works).
**My problem is solved now for iOS (Phone and tablet), Android (phone and tablet) and WP (phone) (only platforms on which I show the pages).**
So.. I accept the answer from Ivan (em-tip), what does not mean that the answer from Vinc is wrong/bad (if I would need the pages universal, I would checkout all in detail, as I have to learn much to css...:-).
**My implemented class to the link as button:**

```
.WP_Link {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 4em;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    color: #333333;
    color: #00C;
    padding: 4px 6px 4px 6px;
    border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-right: 1px solid #333333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
    border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```